# CodingKeys not working in mongodb realm sync

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

How to override Mongo properties for my model class in Swift. Because I use a different standard than the nomenclature that is in the cloud. Ex.: (in swift: partition, in cloud: _partition).

### Expected Results

I hope I don't have to write my classes in Swift with the same nomenclature used on the servers.

### Code Sample

```swift
class Project: Object, Codable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var partition = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case partition = "_partition"
        case name
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(partition: String, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.partition = partition
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

### Version of Realm and Tooling

Realm framework version: `pod 'RealmSwift', '=10.0.0-beta.2'`

Realm Object Server version: 4.4.0-rc9

Xcode version: 11.5 (11E608c)

iOS/OSX version: 13.5

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Realm objects properties need to match what's in Mongo.

So if you've named the property `_partition` via the Mongo web console, your object will need to have a matching property `_partition`.

At least that's been our experience so far. Our objects key is `_partitionKey` and so our Realm object must match

```
class TaskClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partitionKey = ""
```

here's where that is in the MongoDB console.

[image]

Comment: In Kotlin/Java it is possible to place the annotation @ RealmField ("name_Field"), similar to the @ SerializedName ("name_Field") of the Gson library.
But in Swift I couldn't solve this problem, even using the Codable class.

Comment: @LeonardoFigueiredo I don't think it's really a problem as such - just the way it is. If you want to use the word 'partition' as the objects mongo partition key, why not just define that in the MongoDB console as well? That partition key is really for mongo to organize the objects so as long as it's the same in both the console and object you should be good to go.

Comment: We already have a large project running in Mongo and realm on cell phones.
Before using the stitch I used to make my CodingKeys normally, I'm looking for an alternative to use so that I don't have to rename all properties of all my classes.

Comment: _partition it was just an example, the notation of the fields on the server are as follows: free_access, date_published, etc. In the application all are mapped in another format: freeAccess, datePublished ...

Comment: @LeonardoFigueiredo Ah. I see. Based on what we've seen, whatever partition key was defined in the console has to match the property of the Realm object. I don't think there's  way around that. However, I am wondering if you can add a `_partition` property to satisfy that requirement and have an unmanaged `property` as a front for it so you could still use coding. It would require a migration to assign the `_partition` initially. Just thinking out loud here.